# How to clear textbox in angular2

Tags: angular

**I have loop running suppose 5 times.** so five textbox with clear button will be created.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of array">
  <input id="textFilter" mdInput [ngModel]="searchQuery" value="searchQuery">
    <button>Clear</button>
</div>
```

On click of the Clear button, I want to clear each text box individually.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try: <button (click)="searchQuery = ' ' "></button>

Comment: Is your input value inside of your array?

Comment: It's worth noting that you have an ngFor, but you don't directly access those items in that within your input. Clearing this will be as easy as what Lalit Sachdeva wrote for the answer, but this isn't sufficient to access these items separately within your component.

Comment: @Giovane values are not inside array.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated code

```
 <div *ngFor="let i of array">
      <input id="textFilter" mdInput [ngModel]="searchQuery" value="searchQuery">
        <button (click)="searchQuery = ''">Clear</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

In HTML:

```
<input id="textFilter" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" value="searchQuery">
<button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
```

In JS:

```
clear(){
    this.searchQuery = "";
}
```

Don't forget to import `FormsModule`

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IaDPUgXilENEuc79NPRE?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of array;let index = index;">
    <input id="textFilter" mdInput [(ngModel)]="searchQuery[index]" value="searchQuery">
    <button (click)=clear(index)>Clear</button>
</div>
```

In JS:

```
clear(index){
    this.searchQuery[index] = "";
}
```

Updated Plunker [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WRzWKSh86eKbmOtJdpp1?p=preview)

Comment: Everything getting clear. I want to clear them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Updated)

```
'<div *ngFor="let i of array; let j = index">
    <input [id]="'textFilter'+j" mdInput [ngModel]="searchQuery" value="searchQuery">
    <button (click)="document.getElementById('textFilter"+j+"').reset()">Clear</button>
</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the ngModel value to a property of searchQuery, and use that property to clear each searchQuery value.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of array;let index = index;">
  <input id="textFilter" mdInput [(ngModel)]="searchQuery[index]" 
value="searchQuery">
    <button (click)=clear(index)>Clear</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jusMalcom. i'll just extrapolate on the .ts

```
    export class A {
private searchQuery: string[] = new Array();

constructor() {}

clear(idx: any) {
 this.searchQuery[idx] = '';
}
}
```

hope that helps.
Ashley

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why nobody mentioned this yet but:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of array">
    <input id="textFilter" mdInput [ngModel]="i.searchQuery" value="i.searchQuery">
    <button (click)="i.searchQuery=''">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Is the simplest and most efficient way to do what you are asking for, so long as it won't affect the rest of your code to add an additional parameter to the objects in your array.

If it affect something else in your code, then using @JusMalcolm answer is the best solution.

In order to have a "searchQuery" on each of the items in your array, well you need to have the same amount of searchQueries stored somewhere. It is far simpler to store it alongside your items but storing it separately in a second array is perfectly fine as well.